# How to access iOS VPN API from Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, vpn

I know it is impossible to create new VPN profiles, but applications of VPN companies can at least toggle on/off connection on already installed ones.

How can you access this using Xamarin.ios?

for android, you get lots of options in Android.Net.VpnService but for iOS I cant find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can utilise `NetworkExtension.framework`. In general you can load and manipulate your own App's system preferences through this framework. [This](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) article will help you very well solving the problem :)